# no #[repr(...)] for rust crate

Tags: rust, enums, rust-crates

I'm trying to solve a trivially simple exercism task on using external crates.

```
use int_enum::IntEnum;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, IntEnum)]

pub enum ResistorColor {
    Black = 0,
    Brown = 1,
    Red = 2,
    Orange = 3,
    Yellow = 4,
    Green = 5,
    Blue = 6,
    Violet = 7,
    Grey = 8,
    White = 9,
}

pub fn value_to_color_string(value: u32) -> String {
    match ResistorColor::from_int(value) {
        Ok(r) => format!("{:?}", r),
        Err(r) => "value out of range".to_string(),
    }
}
```

which gives me an error stating that `no #[repr(...)] found`

And further when using methods from the package:

```
pub fn value_to_color_string(value: u32) -> String {
    match ResistorColor::from_int(value) {
        Ok(r) => format!("{:?}", r),
        Err(r) => "value out of range".to_string(),
    }
}
```

I get an error when using the method `from_int(value)`

```
items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
the following trait defines an item 'from_int', perhaps you need to implement it:
candidate #1: 'IntEnum'
```

When checking similar solutions, they are implemented in the exact same way as mine. Any tips?

Comment: Where does `ResistorColor` come from?

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I guess what might be the problem, but it's impossible to be sure without full context.

Comment: Yes, what @Cerberus said. Your `#derive`, for example, makes no sense without an item attached to it.

Comment: I've added the full context now. It's my second day learning Rust and second question on stack, so still fairly new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not documented, but apparently `#[derive(IntEnum)]` requires the enum to have a [`#[repr(integer)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#primitive-representation-of-field-less-enums), for each variant to have an explicit integer value (`Name = value`), and in addition [the `IntEnum` trait requires the type to be `Copy`](https://docs.rs/int-enum/latest/int_enum/trait.IntEnum.html).